# Ways to create CDATA sections in XML

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, cdata

To render data using XSLT, for CDATA section in XML is there only one solution using `cdata-section-elements`:

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="someNodeName" />
```

Or is there any other solution other then this one?

Comment: Can you expand on this further? What have you tried? Do you have any code?